# Why is there a factor of half in the definition of bond order?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I was recently taught about molecular orbital theory and bond order:

$$\text{Bond order} = \frac{\text{Number of bonding electrons} - \text{Number of antibonding electrons}}{2}$$

I was wondering, what is the purpose of dividing by 2?

Answer (score 1):

Because there are two electrons in a covalent bond! Say all the electrons you have is two bonding electrons... Would you call that a bond order of two? Or is it just a good old single bond?